# PHP permission levels from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with columns:

1. sequence
2. page_name
3. level_user
4. level_support
5. level_accounts
6. level_admin

the last 4 columns are the access levels (user, support, accounts and admin)

here is the code i am using to check the permissions:

```
$permission_sql="SELECT * from admin_permissions where page_name = '".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."' ";
$permission_rs=mysql_query($permission_sql,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($permission_rs) == 0)
{
    echo '<h2 align="center">An Error has occurred!</h2>';
    exit();
}
else
{
    $permission_result=mysql_fetch_array($permission_rs);
    if($usertype_user != $permission_result["level_user"])
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
    if($usertype_support != $permission_result["level_support"])
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
    if($usertype_admin != $permission_result["level_admin"])
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
    if($usertype_accounts != $permission_result["level_accounts"])
    {
        echo '<h2 align="center">Access Denied</h2>';
        echo '<h2 align="center">Please contact your administrator quoting \'Permission Error\' and number \''.$permission_result["sequence"].'\'</h2>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

i am accessing: /admin/index.php so my query is saying

select * from admin_permissions where page_name = '/admin/index.php'

then my if statements run and the user i am logged in as has `$usertype_admin` set as 'yes' and `$permission_result["level_admin"]` is equal to 'yes' but its displaying the Access denied error which shouldn't be as $usertype_admin does == $permission_result["level_admin"]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: how would you do what  i am trying to achieve then?

Comment: structure as follows: sequence - pagename - user_access and you just assign a number to each level of user access. This allows for expansion or reduction

Comment: @charlie I've updated my answer with one solution - it explains the problem with the conditional check. However, the logic I present might not be exactly what is called for, which needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

While I present a proposal below in the second section, her is an explanation of "why" the code doesn't work, based on the updated question/information.

> Then my if statements run and the user i am logged in as has $usertype_admin set as 'yes' and $permission_result["level_admin"] is equal to 'yes' but its displaying the Access denied error which shouldn't be as $usertype_admin does == $permission_result["level_admin"]

This is because *if any* of the `if` branches are true the error message will be displayed and `exit` will be called - note that the condition for each case `!=`. Imagine this data:

```
(permission)  $user   database  $user != database
------------  ------  --------  -----------------
user          yes     no        TRUE
support       yes     no        TRUE
admin         yes     yes       FALSE
accounts      yes     no        TRUE
```

Then it can be seen that, even though the user is an administrator (e.g. `$user(user)` is 'yes'), and the page only "asks for" the administrator permission, the authorization will fail because `$user(user)` is 'yes' while `database(user)` is 'no'. Whoops.

Here is one approach that requires a matching permission *only if* set to non-'no' in the database:

```
function hasAllPermissions ($permissions) {
    // Note the use of a NEGATIVE selector on the database value
    if($permission_result["level_admin"] != 'no'
            && $usertype_admin != $permission_result["level_admin"]) {
        // Only here if a permission is set OTHER than 'no' and it does
        // not equal the currently assigned user permission.
        return FALSE;
   }
   // .. the other checks
   // If we haven't rejected yet, the the database either asks for
   // no permissions or we pass all permission checks.
   return TRUE;
}

// In check:
if (!hasAllPermissions($permission_result)) {
   // display warning and exist
}
```

Or, perhaps we want the inverse:

```
function hasAnyPermission ($permissions) {
    // Note the use of a POSITIVE selector on the database value
    if($permissions["level_admin"] != 'no'
            && $usertype_admin == $permissions["level_admin"]) {
        // We matched, so accept as having permission and return to
        // avoid the additional checks.
        return TRUE;
    }
    // .. the others checks
    // And if nothing succeeded in matching, then we fail.
    return FALSE;
}

// In check:
if (!hasAnyPermission($permission_result)) {
   // display warning and exit
}
```

Note how both forms are almost identical, except for the inversion of the test and return result.

Some changes I would recommend, besides redoing the entire schema (which I do also recommend):

- *Clearly* defining the business rules relating to the permissions
- Using functions - for the conditional logic, and for displaying the warning message
- Using an array for `$usertype_xyx`, such that `$usertype["xyz"]` mirrors `$permission_result["xyz"]` and can be passed around to the appropriate functions

---

(The following was written to address the *original* question and I feel it still holds merit.)

SQL is designed to expand along *rows*, not *columns* - column names should *not contain information*.

When using a column-oriented approach you'll have to add in support for each column name and give it meaning (see "column names should not contain information"). While this could be done based on heuristics and reading the *dynamic* column shape (e.g. from a `SELECT *`), I would advise against this approach.

Instead, the following structure may be a more appropriate start for a database schema with role-based permissions.

```
Users
- Username

Pages
- PageTitle

Roles
- RoleName

Users_Roles -- Granted Roles
- FK Users
- FK Roles

Pages_Roles -- Required (or Denied) Roles
- FK Pages
- FK Roles
```

Then, given a function `hasAllRequiredPermissions($user, $page)`, it is possible to construct a query that will use the above tables to determine if a particular use has *all* the required permissions to view a page and the function *won't require updating* when a new Role is added. This is because the *information* exists in rows - not columns.

Additionally, the above relationships allow the model to be easily extended to allow things like "*Allow* access if User has Role" and "*Deny* access if User has Role".

---

Also, not using placeholders is a *problem* and the posted query with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` could potentially be exploited. Make sure to *use placeholders* when writing the new authentication code.

Comment: @charlie That's fine, the non-working of the current approach is orthogonal to my proposed solution (and the original question). Anyway, the code presented requires that *all* the permissions are granted (that is, all return "yes" and the appropriate PHP variables are all "yes") - increase the error message to say *which* permission was not met and then work from that.

Comment: @charlie If you wish to provide overrides, then simply update the if-structure to *accept* the permissions in order and use an else to reject.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a table called permission_table which would store the pages that each user is allowed to access, pages they aren't allowed to access would not appear here

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+
| permission_id |     page     | user_id  |
+---------------+--------------+----------+
|             1 | home.php     |       33 |
|             2 | accounts.php |        2 |
|             3 | support.php  |       67 |
+---------------+--------------+----------+
```

Then the query for each page would be

```
SELECT * from permissions_table where user_id = :user_id AND page = :page
```

You'd get the currently logged in user's ID from a stored session like $_SESSION['user_id']. You could even store the pages they are allowed to visit in a session array to save database queries

You should use PDO instead of the depretiated "mysql_". The full code would be...

```
session_start(); //This is needed when working with PHP sessions

//The mysql database details
$dbhost = 'your db host';
$dbuser = 'your db username';
$dbpass = 'your db password';
$dbname = 'your db name';

//PDO connection
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//Permissions query
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * from permissions_table WHERE user_id = :user_id AND page = :page');
$stmt->bindParam(':staff_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->bindParam(':page', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

//If PDO query executes and returns 1 row!
if($stmt->execute() && $stmt->rowCount() === 1){
    echo 'Permission granted'!
    } else { die('Permission denied!');
    }
```

The best part is that all of this script could be in a seperate php file that is then included at the top of each page as a require like so...
    require ('permissions.php');

So if the code were to change you would only have to change it once in permissions.php

Alternatively if you just want 4 different permission types instead doing permissions by each page. You can change the page column to 'type'. And store things like 'Admin', 'Support' etc. Then at the top of each page put things like this...

```
$permissiontype = 'Support';
require ('permissions.php');
```

Then change the query and PDO binding to get the variable instead of current page

```
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $permissiontype);
```

Comment: And your log-in script you'd need to edit so that it had something like 
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
if it doesn't already

Comment: Even if it is '/admin/' my code would work if you stored the values in the database without '/admin/'. Otherwise you could do
$currentpage = '/admin/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); and then update the PDO query to use $currentpage

Comment: See my edit. I changed the bottom part of my question

Comment: Process of elimination. First you could find out if it works with '/admin/index.php' in place of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] but the alternate method I proposed is better so please up-vote!

Comment: I don't know anything about PDO which is why I didn't use it. I'm not worried about sql injection on this occasion. Also I want to be able to have multiple permissions and set them in the database not on each page. For example give admin and user access to one page

Comment: also perhaps you should use $_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’] or $_SERVER[’SCRIPT_NAME’] instead of REQUEST_URI because REQUEST_URI also takes URIs...things like ?id=25&othervalue=value&another=10

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sql query. That is working fine

Comment: The script I provided is complete and should work without any extra work except for adding the table and filling out the username and password details! PDO is much more secure - no need to do mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Look at what I am saying. Read my previous comment about PDO!

Comment: So even though mysql_ is going to be removed from PHP (thus breaking your your website), you want to use it anyway? I was only trying to help, I don't think that calls for a down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

"mysql_fetch_array" returns a zero-indexed array for the row.  If you want the *column names* to be indexes within the row, then you should use "mysql_fetch_assoc".  For more information on using that function, see this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Basically, you're getting back:

```
$permission_result[0] = whatever "sequence" is
$permission_result[1] = the page name that you asked for
$permission_result[2] = value of level_user
$permission_result[3] = value of level_support
$permission_result[4] = value of level_accounts
$permission_result[5] = value of level_admin
```

So, when you ask for

```
$permission_result["level_user"]
```

it turns out that "$permission_result" has no element called "level_user", so it gives you "null" as the result.  I'm pretty sure that your permission variables for the user are booleans (true/false) or characters (such as 'y' and 'n'), they won't match the null value that you're getting by checking

```
$permission_result["level_user"]
```

Switch "mysql_fetch_array" to "mysql_fetch_assoc" and you'll probably be fine.